# google spreadsheet IF a cell contains some words included in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to check if a cell contains some words included in another cell, if yes it should say "Valid".
For example, if cell A2 is Jon Doe Street and cell B2 is 230 Jon Doe it should say "valid"
I'm using this formula
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B2,C2)),"Valid","")
but it only works for some rows.
This is a sample you can check
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S5m_kV0td9_nq8vWZGkSneCEXGnLHL_af1hlzn2sz0I/edit?usp=sharing
How can i fix it?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(SUM(BYCOL(SPLIT(B2," "),LAMBDA(ax,IFERROR(--REGEXMATCH(C2,ax)))))>=2,"VALID",)
```

- 

arrayformula

`=MAP(B2:B,C2:C,LAMBDA(abx,cx,IF(SUM(BYCOL(SPLIT(abx," "),LAMBDA(ax,IFERROR(--REGEXMATCH(cx,ax)))))>=2,"VALID",)))`

-

[image]